# How do you give components a name in react?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, ecmascript-5

When I am debugging using the browser console console or react dev tools, they always refer to my components as "Constructor" and I would like to change that. See the example below:

[image: Example error message]

I would have hoped to set defined names for my components so they would show up as "MyComponent" for example. This would help on pages where there are many components and one of them is throwing a warning that I would like to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the [`displayName`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#displayname) property to your components:

```
var Component = React.createClass({  
  displayName: 'MyComponent',
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `displayName` property to your components actually. It is automatically set.

But there are certain cases you need to consider.

**1**.You put your component in a separate file and content of that file is -

```
 export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
});
```

In this case `displayName` will be `undefined`.

**2**.You assigned the component in a variable.

```
var TestComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
});
```

Now `displayName` is set to `TestComponent`.

See corresponding `jsx` conversion for more clarification.

```
var TestComponent = React.createClass({
  displayName: "TestComponent",

  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      "h1",
      null,
      "Hello, ",
      this.props.name
    );
  }
});
```

**3**.If you are using es6 e.g

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <div > Hello component {
      } < /div>;
  }
}
```

In this case `displayName` will be name of class you have given i.e `HelloMessage`.

Comment: This isn't quite right for your second case. Which is the exact variant that we use. displayName will be "Constructor" in our case. This might be because of Reactjs.NET though.

Comment: Added corresponding jsx transformation for more clarification.

Comment: @Perfection I don't know how it get transformed in Reactjs.NET and you may be right that something different may be happening there.